# How do I execute an index.php page in an Azure App Service?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've created an Azure App Service and I've set the PHP version to 5.6 (though I've experimented with different versions and it doesn't seem to matter).

[image]
I've deployed the world's simplest PHP script in `index.php` (via a git local repo method):

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
echo "hello";
?>
```

When I access the URL for my App Service, the page is blank and the view source is just the script contents. Which is to say that it's not being processed and rendered as PHP.

I know PHP is doing *something*. I know this because if I turn the PHP version off in the App Service settings, I get an error message "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." when accessing the page. So it only serves `.php` pages when PHP is on. That's sensible, except it's not actually processing the script.

I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `index.php` in the **Default documents** section in app Settings of your Azure Web App, to approach your requirement.

[image]

Comment: `index.php` is there by default.

It doesn't seem to make a difference if I access `http://name.azurewebsites.net/` or `http://name.azurewebsites.net/index.php` -- they both behave the same way by returning the text of the PHP script.

Comment: Could you please check whether there is a `web.config` file in your root directory on Azure Web Apps? And could you provide the content in your `web.config`